# Duplicate value exception while inserting into an autoincremental-PK table

Tags: database, exception, insert, sql-server-ce

I recently experienced a `SqlCeException`: "A duplicate value cannot be inserted into a unique index" while inserting a record in a table (SqlCE 3.5).

It seems the INSERT statement violates the primary key constraint. However, on the relevant table, the PK has been defined as an autoincrementing identity:

```
[ID] int identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
```

The exception is not systematical: it happens once in a while.

What could be the cause of this exception?
Doesn't the `identity(1,1)` guarantee a unique ID for each INSERT, does it?
Could this be a SqlCE bug? If so, how could it be circumvented?

Here is the Exception trace (it explicitly refers to the PK_ID constraint):

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: A duplicate value cannot be inserted into a unique index. [ Table name = HistoricalData,Constraint name = PK_ID ]
  at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ProcessResults(Int32 hr)
  at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommandText(IntPtr& pCursor, Boolean& isBaseTableCursor)
  at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, ResultSetOptions options)
  at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
  at Invensys.Compact.Persistence.SqlCe.PlantData.SaveHistoricalRecord(HistoricalRecord record)
  at ...
```

Table definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE [HistoricalData] ( 
[ID] int identity(1,1)  NOT NULL,
[Timestamp] datetime NOT NULL,
[Type] smallint NOT NULL,
[IDLastAll] int,
[IDRef] int NOT NULL,
[BinaryLength] smallint NOT NULL,
[Data00] varbinary(500),
[Data01] varbinary(500),
[Data02] varbinary(500),
[Data03] varbinary(500),
[Data04] varbinary(500),
[Data05] varbinary(500),
[Data06] varbinary(500),
[Data07] varbinary(500),
[Data08] varbinary(500),
[Data09] varbinary(500));


--  Create Primary Key Constraints 
ALTER TABLE [HistoricalData] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_ID] 
    PRIMARY KEY ([ID]);

--  Create Indexes 
CREATE INDEX [IDX_Type_Timestamp]
ON [HistoricalData] ([Type] ASC, [Timestamp] ASC);

CREATE INDEX [IDX_Timestamp]
ON [HistoricalData] ([Timestamp] ASC);
```

The INSERT is performed via a SqlCeCommand. Here is the code (C#):

```
 _insertRecordCommand =
     new SqlCeCommand
     {
         Connection = _connection,
         CommandType = CommandType.Text,
         CommandText = HISTORICAL_DATA_INSERT
     };

 _insertRecordCommand.Parameters.Add("@Timestamp", SqlDbType.DateTime);
 _insertRecordCommand.Parameters.Add("@Type", SqlDbType.SmallInt);
 _insertRecordCommand.Parameters.Add("@IDLastAll", SqlDbType.Int);
 _insertRecordCommand.Parameters.Add("@IDRef", SqlDbType.Int);
 _insertRecordCommand.Parameters.Add("@BinaryLength", SqlDbType.Int);

 for (var i = 0; i < DATA_BLOCK_NUMBER; i++)
 {
    _insertRecordCommand.Parameters.Add(DATAPARAMETERNAMES[i], SqlDbType.VarBinary, DATA_BLOCK_SIZE);
 }

 _insertRecordCommand.Prepare();

 // Here the parameters are filled.

 _insertRecordCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I left out how parameters are filled. Nevertheless, there is no [ID] (the primary key) parameter.

Comment: What is the code you use please? Also, a unique index violation is different to a PK violation

Comment: Please post the table definition including any other unique indexes. You are probably violating some other unique index constraint. You can catch the exception and examine your SQL to see if you are trying to insert a duplicate value in another column.

Comment: I suspect that your table already has data and that your identity seed has been reset to 1, maybe when migrating from another database? Please check the content of the table and if the table contains rows, set your identity seed to something higher than the highest ID in the table (select max(ID) from HistorycalData).

Comment: Hmmm... it could be. I'm going to check. Thank you Andreas.